# How to check the number of edgenods?

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

how to check the number of edgenods, if I want to check namenode, I'm using the command: `hdfs getconf -namenodes`. How can i find edgenode?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition an edge node is a node that does not run any services and only has client configuration installed on it. Therefore, the cluster does not track edgenodes and there is no way to find a count of them. In theory, any host with the correct configuration could be an edge node for the cluster.